# Search multilevel javascript array by object key value

Tags: javascript

i have this obj

```
  var myObj =   {
    "sections": [{
        "id": "s1",
        "name": "my section no.1",
        "sheets": [{
            "id": "sheet1",
            "questions": [{
                "id": "q1",
                "name": "my q",
                "options": [{
                    "id": "o1",
                    "order_no": 1,
                    "name": "option 1"
                }, {
                    "id": "o2",
                    "name": "option 2"
                }]
            }]
        }]
    }]
};
```

i want function to search this array by id 
so 
searchById("o1") should return

```
{"id": "o1","order_no": 1,"name": "option 1"}
```

and  searchById("q1") should return

```
{
    "id": "q1",
    "name": "my q",
    "options": [{
        "id": "o1",
        "order_no": 1,
        "name": "option 1"
    }, {
        "id": "o2",
        "name": "option 2"
    }]
}
```

please help me

Answer (score 4):

What you have is object and you can create recursive function using `for...in` loop to return result.

```js
var obj = {
  "sections": [{
    "id": "s1",
    "name": "my section no.1",
    "sheets": [{
      "id": "sheet1",
      "questions": [{
        "id": "q1",
        "name": "my q",
        "options": [{
          "id": "o1",
          "order_no": 1,
          "name": "option 1"
        }, {
          "id": "o2",
          "name": "option 2"
        }]
      }]
    }]
  }]
}

function findObj(data, id) {
  for (var i in data) {
    if (i == 'id' && data[i] == id) return data
    if (typeof data[i] == 'object' && findObj(data[i], id)) return findObj(data[i], id)
  }
}

console.log(findObj(obj, 'o1'))
console.log(findObj(obj, 'q1'))
```

Comment: your function not iterating all keys so i posted new answer find it out

Comment: no  i added a condition before return in second if clause 
`if (typeof data[i] == 'object' && findObj(data[i], id))`

Comment: What is that doing? Also could you provide example of data in https://jsfiddle.net/ where my code fails so i could fix it?

Comment: the function will skip any key after objects

Answer (score 0):

```
 myArray =    {
    "sections": [{
        "id": "s1",
        "name": "my section no.1",
        "sheets": [{
            "id": "sheet1",
            "questions": [{
                "id": "q1",
                "name": "my q",
                "options": [{
                    "id": "o1",
                    "order_no": 1,
                    "name": "option 1"
                }, {
                    "id": "o2",
                    "name": "option 2"
                }]
            }]
        }]
    }]
}


 myArray = JSON.parse(myArray).sections;
   function getMeObjById(criteria) {
     var myObj = myArray.filter(funcion(obj){
      if(obj.id !== 'undefined' && obj.id === criteria){
       return true;
      }
     });
     return myObj; // or return myObj[0] if id are unique
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide an explanation for this ?

Answer (score 0):

```
function findID(id, object){
    let _temp;
    // Verify if is Array
    if(object instanceof Array){
        // Scan all objects by doing recursion
        for(let i = 0; i < object.length; i++){
            if((_temp = findID(id, object[i]))){
                return _temp;
            }
        }
    }   

    // Verify if is Object
    if(object instanceof Object){
        // Verify if is the Object ID
        if(object.id && object.id === id){
            return object;
        }
        // Scan all objects by doing recursion
        for(index in object){
            if(object[index] instanceof Object || object[index] instanceof Array){
                if((_temp = findID(id, object[index]))){
                    return _temp;
                }
            }   
        }
    }
}
```